# Switching between Web and Native iOS Firebase SDK

Tags: angularjs, firebase, native, hybrid

I am developing an hybrid app and for the moment only using the web Firebase SDK.

I am now realising that I might have to skip javascript for certains things like when the app is in the background and JS execution is not always possible. At such, I might have to do certain things in native. Hence my question:

If my user is logged using the Javascript SDK, what will happen when switching to the native SDK within the same app ? More specifically, what about authentication ?

Answer (score 0):

Authentication state is not shared between web and native application. The user will have to authenticate with both in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks Frank - so would the only viable way be to use a cordova plugin which wraps around the native iOS and Android SDK, therefore offering javascript functions while leveraging the native functions and shared native/web authentication ?